# Move function with Splice in Python

Tags: javascript, python, list, function

I'm trying to figure out how to do this following function from Javascript to Python:

```
function arraymove(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    var element = arr[fromIndex];
    arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    arr.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
}
```

Of course in Python we'de be working with Tuples and I'm not sure if there's a function like Splice in order to achive the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `insert` *method* and move the *desired* element using just one line of code.

You would have to *delete* it and then just *insert* it at the `new` position. Using `pop` method you can remove one element from a specified position.

```
l.pop(fromIndex)
```

Then just use `insert` method and pass as *argument* the position where you want to insert the element.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
def arraymove(arr, fromIndex, toIndex):
  l.insert(toIndex, l.pop(fromIndex))

print(l)
arraymove(l, 3, 1)
print(l)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 2, 3, 5]
```